# Why WindowsUpdate Policy does not exist for me in Registry?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

I am running Windows 7 and I can not fix my Windows Updater. I heard that I have to reset the following registry key for that to work:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate
```

However, this key does not exist in my registry. Why do I not have it, and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: What is the issue with Windows Updater? Did you check the "Windows Update" settings are enabled in your machine (Control Panel > Windows Updates)? If the registry key is not present in the path, then you can create the respective registry key and registry values in order to take effect on an update.

Comment: @vembutech when I try to update, it gives me an error with a code "0x80244019"

Comment: @vembutech to fix it, I found that I have to reset that registry key, but it is not there. Do you know why?

Comment: Some malware will prevent Windows Update from working.  Have you checked your system with a reliable AV or Anti Malware tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment try creating registry key with the following code

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"DetectionFrequency"=dword:00000001
"DetectionFrequencyEnabled"=dword:00000001
"NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers"=dword:00000000
```

Open notepad and save the above content as "update.reg" and save it to desktop

Right click on the saved file to merge into registry.

Comment: Thanks, it created the key. But windows still doesn't seem to use that key for the Windows Update information. Do you know why, or where is the key that is used by WindowsUpdate?

Comment: Try resetting windows update components using the link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058

Comment: @user402935 have you checked for malware?  Everytime I find someone's windows update not working I also find malware.  If it's already been removed then vembutech's link should help